# Deploying Azure SQL Server with external data sources

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, continuous-deployment, sql-server-data-tools, external-data-source

I have two environments, development and production. Each one of them has 2 databases, one main database and another that is used as an external data source.

Currently I'm trying to create a github deployment pipeline, I use SSDT to do source control and I have the actions for building the `.dacpac` and sending it to Azure working. How can I configure so that when in production the database looks to external source of prod, instead of the same external source as dev, when I deploy changes to production?

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on your scenario? I think you have a separate external sources for dev and prod?

Comment: Yes there is one external source that we use for testing and one for production @KarthikBhyresh-MT

Comment: Would you please elaborate on your scenario? What is this external source, how are you connecting to it ? More specifics would help me to answer accurately for your setup